# Can a Regex be written to find numbers in a string greater than x?

Tags: regex, validation

Can a Regex be written to find numbers in a string that are greater than x?

Say for example x = 1800

Can we find for that a number > 1800 which is in the strings: "3,000.00/month" | "$2800" | "150,000.00a month" | "only $1900" etc?  The regex would find 3,000.00, 2800, 150,000.00 and 1900 because they are all greater than 1899.

What is this pattern that elludes me..

Comment: I don't see a 1800 in your string. Only a 2800 and a 1900

Comment: Regexes do not calculate. You need a function that matches "all numbers" (or, given your constraints, at least those of >= 4 digits). Then in that function, convert the found string to a number and test.

Comment: A regex is unlikely to be a good tool to use here, at least on its own. Show us more of the context, such as where the inputs are coming from and what you're doing to process them after you have the numbers you want.

Comment: The context is that only regex can be used to solve the problem. Do you think it is impossible?

Comment: I would use regex to extract the number strings, then range check in app code. While theoretically possible to do it purely in regex, it's a waste of time. Another option is to extract the numbers beforehand and store them in a database and use app code to find hits, but it depends in your exact circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find any well-formatted number greater than a number with a regular expression, but it does get more complicated as the numbers get bigger.

Let's start with a simple example where x = 11, and you wanted to find any number in a string greater than 11.  The regex you'd write would follow a pattern similar to the solution below:

```
(\d{3,}|[2-9]\d|1[2-9])(\.\d+)?|11\.\d*[1-9]\d*
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/qqx6zr)

What is the purpose of first three inner alternations?  The first captures any three or more digit number, the second any two digit number where the digit in the 10's place is 2-9, and the last any two digit number where the digit in the 10's place is 1 and the digit in the 1's place is 2-9.  Then it optionally captures any decimal decimal digits.

The second outer alternation actually matches x in the integer part, but then checks the decimal part to ensure it is somehow greater.  If you had a decimal part of 12 for x then you'd just do `120*\d*|1[3-9]\d*|2\d*`.

There are two situations that will make the above pattern not work:

- When a number contains commas
- When a number starts with zeroes.

The example below deals with those cases as well and solves for x = 1800.

```
#FIND any number > 1800
(?=[1-9])                            # ensure number doesn't begin with a zero
(
  (\d{1,3},(?=\d{3}))*\d{2,3},\d{3}| # any number that has >= 5 digits with commas   
  \d{5,}|                            # any number that has >= 5 digits without commas
  [2-9],?\d{3,}|                     # any 4 digit number that starts with 2-9
  1,?9\d{2}|                         # any 4 digit number that starts with 1 then 2-9
  1,?8[1-9]\d|                       # any 4 digit number that starts with 18 then 1-9
  1,?80[1-9]                         # any 4 digit number that starts with 180 then 1-9
)
(\.\d+)?                             # any decimal digits
|1,?800\.\d*[1-9]\d*                 # any number whoses integer = 1800, 
                                     # ... then has a decimal with a non-zero digit.
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/u6ro37)

At the top of the regex is uses a look ahead to ensure a number actually starts with 1-9.  Without it a number like 00005 would be confused as a five digit number.

The inner group finds all integer matches greater than 1800, just like the first example tried to match numbers greater than eleven.  Probably, the only non obvious alternation is the first - `(\d{1,3},(?=\d{3}))*\d{2,3},\d{3}`.  To find a 5+ digit number it matches 1-3 digits followed by a comma, then 2-3 digits, a comma and then the last 3 digits.  Without the look ahead it would incorrectly match a non-number such as 234,23,412.

If you're going to be picky about commas, like I am being, then you're not going to be able to integrate comma and non-comma cases such as with `1,?9\d{2}` => 1914 & 1,914.  Having multiple `,?` would lead to incorrect matches such as 1000,050, when trying to find a number greater than a million.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it in two steps: first find a number and then apply a regex to it that checks if it is greater than you number x.

As an example:
here is a regex that matches numbers **from 31 to 99999**, which you can adjust to your needs:

`^(?:[3][1-9]|[4-9][0-9]|(^[1-9][0-9]{2,4}$))$`
where

- `[3][1-9]` - matches numbers from 31 to 39
- `[4-9][0-9]` - matches numbers from 40 to 99
- `^[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` - matches numbers from 100 to 9999

The last bit `^[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` can be changed to `^[1-9][0-9]{2,}` to match any number greater than 100